# Tampermonkey JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Знаю, что есть такой же вопрос, но у меня всё равно не работает **JQuery** в **Tampermonkey**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Naurok
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       MrKidics
// @match        *
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// @run-at       context-menu
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    console.log('stating...');
    $(function() {});
})();
```

Ошибка в консоли:

```
'$' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `$` брать из глобального объекта

```
(function($) {
    console.log('stating...');
    $(function() {});
})(window.jQuery); //})(window.$);
```

или после строки `// ==/UserScript==` добавить комментарий:

```
/* globals jQuery, $, waitForKeyElements */
```